# Как с помощью библиотеки DocumentFormat.OpenXml вставить xlsx файл в docx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, docx, openxml

В программе, пользователь выбирает файлы, которые можно вложить в docx файл. Добавление картинок я сделал. Как добавлять xlsx и pdf(желательно).

Используемая библиотека: DocumentFormat.OpenXml.

Так я добавляю в документ картинки:

```
public static void InsertAPicture(WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument, MainDocumentPart mainPart, string fileName)
    {
        ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName);
        var width = img.Width;
        var height = img.Height;
        img.Dispose();

        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            imagePart.FeedData(stream);
        }

        AppenderToDoc.AddImageToBody(wordprocessingDocument, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), width, height);
        mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
    }
```

Есть такой пример: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-embed-Excel-sheet-e4c252b5. Но там в docx добавляется картинка при клике на которую открывается xlsx документ. А мне нужно чтобы содержимое этого документа(xlsx) вставилось в docx.

Жду любые предложения.

Comment: посмотрите этот гайд https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-embed-Excel-sheet-e4c252b5

Comment: как раз сейчас его смотрю, пока разбираюсь.

Comment: смысл в том, что вставляется OLE-объект

Comment: У меня в этом месте: `EmbedExcelIntoWordDoc.Properties.Resource1.BASE64_STRING_EXCEL_ICON` пишет does not exists in the current context. Я не знаю что подключить нужно.

Comment: там можно скачать пример, скачайте и увидите, что это ресурс, который добавили в проект.

Comment: Скачал пример. Запустил. В итоге он создал файл ContainingDocument.docx, который почему-то не удается открыть, но если все же его открыть (проигнорировав предупреждение) то там такое содержимое:This is the containing document.
This is the embedded document:

Comment: В итоге все нормально в примере отработало. Но он там создает ярлык, через который можно открыть excel, а мне нужно вставить само содержимое excel в word.

Answer (score 0):

Для добавления содержимого файлов формата XLSX и PDF в документ формата DOCX с использованием библиотеки DocumentFormat.OpenXml, вам потребуется немного другой подход. Вместо добавления картинки, как в случае с изображением, вы будете вставлять содержимое файлов внутри специальных блоков в документе DOCX. Вот примеры для добавления XLSX и PDF:

Добавление XLSX:

```
public static void InsertExcelFile(WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument, MainDocumentPart mainPart, string filePath)
{
    // Создание блока для хранения внедренного объекта XLSX
    EmbeddedObjectPart embeddedObjectPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<EmbeddedObjectPart>("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "rId1");

    // Чтение содержимого XLSX файла
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    // Запись содержимого в блок
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(embeddedObjectPart.GetStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(fileBytes);
    }

    // Создание объекта для отображения внедренного XLSX файла
    AlternativeFormatImportPart afiPart = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Excel, "rId2");
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        afiPart.FeedData(stream);
    }

    // Создание объекта для внедренного контента
    EmbeddedPackagePart embeddedPackagePart = mainPart.AddEmbeddedPackagePart(EmbeddedPackagePartType.OpenXmlPackage, "rId3");

    // Установка связей между блоками
    embeddedObjectPart.EmbeddedPackagePartId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(embeddedPackagePart);
    embeddedPackagePart.FeedData(afiPart.GetStream());

    // Добавление блока в тело документа
    AppenderToDoc.AddEmbeddedObjectToBody(wordprocessingDocument, embeddedObjectPart.RelationshipId);
    mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
}
```

Добавление PDF:

```
public static void InsertPdfFile(WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument, MainDocumentPart mainPart, string filePath)
{
    // Создание блока для хранения внедренного объекта PDF
    EmbeddedObjectPart embeddedObjectPart = mainPart.AddNewPart<EmbeddedObjectPart>("application/pdf", "rId1");

    // Чтение содержимого PDF файла
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    // Запись содержимого в блок
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(embeddedObjectPart.GetStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(fileBytes);
    }

    // Добавление блока в тело документа
    AppenderToDoc.AddEmbeddedObjectToBody(wordprocessingDocument, embeddedObjectPart.RelationshipId);
    mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
}
```

Обратите внимание, что в примере используется вспомогательный метод AppenderToDoc.AddEmbeddedObjectToBody, который вы должны реализовать для добавления блока с внедренным объектом в тело документа. Этот метод должен создавать необходимые элементы XML для

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)